# How to hide error message after right value selected from select box in jQuery.validationEngine along jquery mobile?

Tags: android, validation, jquery-mobile, dropbox, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery validationEngine with jQuery mobile plugin in my mobile page, am validating the dropdown list if it has empty value once I set proper value the error message is not getting in hide samsung galaxy android phones but same is working fine in sony xperia and also in normal web browser(PC), can somebody help to fix this ..

**specifications,**

> jQuery Validation Engine 2.2, jquery-1.8.1.min,  jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min,
>   along with  symfony 1.1
>
> The above is working fine in Android 4.0 but not working in android
>   2.2 and 2.3

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution for the my problem...
I override the validationEngine method on those fields on change of the select box,

```
$('#day').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val()!= '日'){
         $("#day").validationEngine('hide');
    }
    else {
         $("#day").validationEngine('showPrompt', '* 半角数字でご入力して下さい。', 'red',"topLeft",true);
    }
    $("#confirm").validationEngine('detach');
    $("#confirm").validationEngine('attach',{promptPosition : "topLeft"});
});
```